# how to play a mp3 file in vlc with c++

Tags: c++, mp3, vlc, audio-player

I have to write a c++ code which  plays a specified song in VLC. I've made some research but i didn't find too much.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
//#include "VLCWrapper.h"
//#include<libvlccore.dll>
//#include<libvlc.dll>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{

    cout << "Welcome to VLC launcher program!" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter a filename: ";
    string filename;
    getline(cin, filename);

    string comm = "vlc \"";
    comm += filename + "\"";
    system(comm.c_str()); //call VLC with the file "filename"
    return 0;
 }
```

This is what i found, but when i compile appears  'vlc' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file. I need some help, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you don't have `vlc` in path, since when I compile it

(had to add this)

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

it runs fine (I compiled it with `g++`):

```
$ ./a.out 
Welcome to VLC launcher program!
Please enter a filename: Darkside.mp4
VLC media player 2.1.5 Rincewind (revision 2.1.4-49-gdab6cb5)
[0x1888a58] pulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused
[0x1770028] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
[0x7f8288001248] main vout display error: Failed to resize display
```

You could try to replace `vlc` with the full path (eg. `/usr/bin/vlc`)...

In case you are on Windows (poor you), it will be the same, just google the "is not internal or external command" and there will be some tips on how to fix it.

Also, you will need `vlc.exe` probably, I have never used command line on Windows, so not sure how it works there.